# How to keep CSS3 Animation still after finishing, then reverting after mouse goes away

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, animation, keyframe

I have a question regarding CSS3 animations/transforms. Typically, I can always find my way around CSS3 - as it's so simple, but this one has been giving me trouble.

What I have is a picture of a plus sign. When the user hovers over the plus sign, it rotates 360 degrees and the picture changes to a minus sign. Everything's working well, except when the animation finishes it reverts quickly back to the plus sign; I want it to stay on the minus sign until the mouse hovers out, then it can go back to the plus sign.

Here's my code:

```
#lock-screen #time-section .unlock {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 23px;
    background-image: url('../images/metro_icon_pack/plus.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#lock-screen #time-section .unlock:hover {
    animation: rotate 1s;
    -o-animation: rotate 1s;
    -ms-animation: rotate 1s;
    -moz-animation: rotate 1s;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        background-image: url('../images/metro_icon_pack/minus.png');
    }
}
```

Now, I realize I only am giving code for WebKit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari). That's because I'm testing it in Chrome, and I will later add further support for other browsers once I get it.

Thanks for any help, guys!

Comment: You should **always put the unprefixed property last**. Right now, Firefox supports unprefixed animations, but the unprefixed property doesn't get applied the way you've written the code, since the `-moz-` prefixed one comes after it and gets applied. Also, while I completely agree with the answer (transitions are what you should use in this case), I also think you might want to look at the `animation-fill-mode` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place the *minus* background image under `#lock-screen #time-section .unlock:hover` and just add a single-second background-image transition.

Also, rather than using 0%, 100% you could just use from, to...

Like:

```
#lock-screen #time-section .unlock:hover {
background-image: url('../images/metro_icon_pack/minus.png');
-webkit-transition: background-image 1s;
/* Other -vendor-transitions go here */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cxrjx/).

I would also go with the transform approach rather than animations and just use transitions (you'll also be able to rotate the element back to the plus sign)...
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJR5p/).

If you don't want to rotate the element back to the plus sign, just add the `-webkit-transition` to the hover state.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJR5p/1/).

Comment: Wow, thanks! Very good input, and the answer I will go with. Thanks again!